# Mobile Site does not show italic text

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web, google-chrome, android

Stats:

- Android 4.1.2
- Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE (TouchViz)
- Chrome browser 27.0.1453.90

I posted a question recently in ELL, and when I looked at it using my smartphone browser, I noticed that text that is supposed to be in italics is in regular font. This negates the effect I wish to achieve by using italics for readers using their mobile phones.

Mobile phone browsers are fully capable of displaying italic text, so I'm not sure what the issue is. I remember noticing this several months ago, but it's still there and has not been fixed yet.

Please let me know if you need test cases, screenshots or any other additional info.

Comment: Screenshots will almost always be helpful with UI issues...

Comment: This is local to one or two devices; just wait for Google to fix it.

Comment: This is not SE's fault, it's a browser bug that affects other sites. Better to let the browsers fix this one that tinker with work around (which as far as I know doesn't exist) for a couple browser versions on a couple devices.

Comment: Hmm ok.. yea, seems like a font issue in Android. The sans-serif font doesn't italicize: http://jsbin.com/peter/3